# How to insert array fields data in Laravel5

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

How can I insert multiple text fields data with Laravel.
I have two fields.

```
<input type="text" name="title[]" />
<input type="text" name="email[]" />
```

Now in controller I can get these values as below.

```
$name =  $request->title;
$description =  $request->email;
```

Here what i get when i print these values.

```
Array
(
    [0] => title1
    [1] => title2
)
Array
(
    [0] => desc1
    [1] => desc2
)
```

How can I add this with eloquent.

Comment: where is your eloquent models ? What value you are getting in $name ? Could you please print it and update the question ?

Comment: I have updated the question with output

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Method 1 :**

```
$name =  $request->title;
    $description =  $request->email;

    if(count($name) > count($description))
        $count = count($description);
    else $count = count($name);


for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
    $objModel = new ModelName();
    $objModel->name = $name[$i];
    $objModel->description = $description[$i];
    $objModel->save();
}
```

**Method 2 :**

```
$name =  $request->title;
    $description =  $request->email;

    if(count($name) > count($description))
        $count = count($description);
    else $count = count($name);

    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
        $data = array(
            'name' => $name[$i],
            'description' => $description[$i]
        );

        $insertData[] = $data;
    }

    ModelName::insert($insertData);
```